# Reading section of CV on Careers shows "add your writing" instead of "add what you've read"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

So I click here:

[image]

And I see:

[image]

Is this a bug or can any one explain it to me?

Comment: Yeah, that caught me off-guard too, good catch.

Comment: My first day on Careers 2.0...=)

Comment: What, you read other people's blog posts and articles too? How utterly unnarcissistic of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed.  Thanks for the report.